# how can i return an array and delete an array in C++ function?

Tags: pointers, return

```
//how can i return an array and delete an array?

int* classA :: aa(double* data, int length){
int* arr = new int[length];
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
arr[i] = data[i];
// please look at this part
return arr;
delete[] arr;
}
```

i want to delete the array 'arr' after allocation and also want to return it.
how can i do both of them?
can i use : 
    x = ClassA.aa(data,length);
    delete[] arr;

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code with delete[] statement is never reached because of previous return statement. I think that you can't do both thinks, because if you delete arr and return pointer after this and will try access some element of it in future in
 would be an undefined behaviour, because the memory is free. So if you want to use this pointer in future don't free memory. Free it when arr is not need.
X = ClassA.aa(data,length); delete[] X.

Comment: Thank for replying! your answer is very helpful to me. thanks again:)